# windows desktop sharing api: How to share a single application

Tags: windows, api, desktop, sharing

I have been recently familiarizing myself with the windows desktop sharing api, and i have a question i cant seem to find the answer to. Is it possible to build an application with the api that only shares the screen of another application that is currently running? Instead of sharing the whole desktop, just the presentation level of a given application that is already running. I appreciate any feedback. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible. According to the details given [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/03/08/windows-desktop-sharing-api.aspx) you can share desktops, regions or individual applications. It sounds like regions is what you want to share.